# Работа с файлом. Python

Tags: python

Не могу понять, почему не находит номер рейса в файле, все время выводит "Не найден".

```
import csv

print("1.Добавить информацию\n2.Поиск информации")
x = int(input())
if x == 1:
    #Ввод пункта назначения рейса
    print("Введите место назначения")
    place = input().upper()

    #Ввод номера рейса
    print("Введите номер рейса")
    num = input().upper()

    #Ввод тип самолета
    print("Введите тип самолета")
    air = input().upper()

    #Запись вводимых данных в файл
    with open("fly.txt", mode = "a", encoding = "utf-8", newline = "") as f:
        file_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ";", lineterminator = "\r")
        file_writer.writerow([place, num, air])
        f.close()

if x == 2:
    d =[]
    with open("fly.txt", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = ";")
        for row in reader:
            d.append(row)
 
    print("Введите номер")
    num = input().upper()
    d1 = []
    for i in d:
        if i.get('номер рейса') == num:
            d1.append(i)
    if len(d1) == 0:
        print("Не найден")
    else:
        for i in d1:
            print(f"{i.get('название пункта назначения рейса')} {i.get('номер рейса')} {i.get('тип самолета')}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При содании экземпляра `csv.DictReader`, необходимо указать параметр:

```
fieldnames=['название пункта назначения рейса', 'номер рейса', 'тип самолета'])
```

В [документации на DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) все написано:

> Если fieldnames не указано, тогда в качестве имен полей будет
> использована первая строка.

А у вас первой строкой имена полей не указываются. Из-за чего:

- `i.get('номер рейса')` - не имеет смысла
- `i.get('название пункта назначения рейса')` - не имеет смысла
- `i.get('тип самолета')` - не имеет смысла

А после указания `fieldnames` все заработает как надо. Вас спасла бы отладка, её необходимо было проделать. Как?

```
    with open("fly.txt", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = ";")
        for row in reader:
            print(row)  # НАПРИМЕР, РАСПЕЧАТАТЬ, ЧТО ЗА ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ ПОПАДАЮТ В d!!!
            d.append(row)
```

И все стало бы очевидно. Ответ либо нашли бы сами в документации - кладезь ответов на многие вопросы. Либо смогли задать более точный вопрос.

PPS: `f.close()` при использовании `with open...` противопоказан, все уже делается автоматически, а ваша "самодеятельность" может привести к странным/страшным ошибкам.